# Open file with absolute path in java

Tags: java, absolute-path

I wrote this code to read the content of a file to a bytes array.
It works fine when `path` (given in the constructor) is relative. But I would like it to work in an absolute path instead. I looked up in java `File` class docs but got confused. How can I changed it to work with absolute path?

```
        File file = new File(path);
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fis.read(bytesArray);
        fis.close();
```

Comment: It has to work with absolute path too. What issue are you facing when absolute path is used?

Comment: What errors do you run into when you use an absolute path? File should be able to take an absolute path without issues.

Comment: Can you show us the value of `path` that fails for you? Absolute paths should work just fine. Keep in mind that Java strings might need you to escape the `\` (i.e. double it) to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code here;

```
File file = new File(path);
```

Your `path` String variable just needs to be absolute instead of relative.

I don't see why it would not work. Did you try to update the path variable to absolute path of your file?

Comment: You are right (and all the commenters to my question) My absolute path was mixed with non english strings. When I gave it only english path it was working just fine. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken in my previous comment. It happend bacuse I had spaces in my absolute path and needed to use " ".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an object from the Path interface using a relative path and getting that path using the Paths class using the static get method. once done you can get the absolute path from the created object and use it as a string if you prefer.

I hope I have helped you.

```java
Path path1 = Paths.get("res/ficheroPrueba.txt");
File file = new File(path1.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).